# Receiving SMS in Android Manifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, sms

I try to receive an sms in my app and I think the problem is in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.amin_amini.smstestmobi"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SMS"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"> 
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My SmsReceive.java is like this

```
package com.amin_amini.smstestmobi;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
         {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }                   
    Toast.makeText(context, "Hey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I'm sure my problem is in manifest.xml because the

```
 Toast.makeText(context, "Hey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

don't show anything.
what should I do ?

edit:
As our friends said bellow I used

```
    Log.i("Hey","Hey" );
```

in my function but nothing will be shown in LogCat
So I'm defenetly sure that my problem is in me AndroidManifest.xml
note: I'm using android 4.0.3 on HTC Sensation

Comment: Don't debug a broadcast receiver with a Toast. Use a log message or a breakpoint. I'm not even sure if you can fire a Toast from one of those.

Comment: yeah, I'm pretty sure that `context` is the Application context, not the activity context.  Won't be able to show dialog's either.  Use Log.i(*).

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change Your receiver code to that, it will help you, if still its not working then may be you have installed another SMS apps which will have higher priority and will abord the broadcast services.

```
     <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast"/> 
             <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I tried that and again it doesn't work on real devices and I do not have anothe SMS app also I've test it on 5 android devices wich it didn't work on the I've put Log.i("Received","Received"); in first line of onReceive but nothing is logged in LogCat :((

Comment: Thanks for help finally I found that my problem is my own phone and when I saw it's not working I changed my AndroidManifest.xml and then I test it on other devices witch it didn't work , my phone has a custom ROM (MIUI) and I think it's sms app priority is higher than anything I changed my sendMessage to sendDataMessage and also my receiver so I can receive it in my app :) thank for help buddy ;)

Comment: @user1905965 , thats great that you got it, keep it up and post any your question on stackoverflow.com, because this forum is the best one for all of us.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code is working fine here.

this is my androidmanifest

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and i have added these permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

or download this [code](http://zohaibbrohi.blogspot.com/2012/11/recieve-sms-and-show-it-in-activity-as.html).. i have made this . it recieve sms and shows in dialog box.

Comment: Thank for help but I previosly added those permissions , also I downloaded your code from dropbox but it doesn's show anything and I only see my sms in my messaging app :(

Comment: try to use log instead of toast. and put some logs in different place in broadcast receiver. it will help you to debug. try it.

Comment: try to run it in android emulator . check if its working or not

Comment: it works fine in an emulator (android 2.2) but it doesn't work on real devices :(